# ||= with hash wrapped in a method

Tags: ruby, hash

I put a hash in a method:

```
def example
  @_hash ||= {:a => {}, :b => {}}
end
```

I call that hash from another method, and add key/value to the sub-hash like so:

```
example[:a][:c] = "test"
```

This will change the hash to:

```
{:a => {:c => "test"}, :b => {}}
```

I don't get why I can still update the `:c` hash by calling the method again like so:

```
example[:a][:c] = "test2" #=>  {:a => {:c => "test2"}, :b => {}}
```

This is odd because the equals/or operator should not assign the values again if `@_hash` is not `nil`/`false`. So I assume we do `example.[]= method` to change the value of an individual hash key/value. If that's true, then why is it that, when I remove `||=` from the hash method like so:

```
def example
  @_hash = {:a => {}, :b => {}}
end
```

nothing is changed?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that, when you call the `example` method again, it correctly returns the following hash:

```
  example #=> {:a => {:c => "test"}, :b => {}}   # variable like syntax
  example() #=> {:a => {:c => "test"}, :b => {}} # method like syntax
```

But, when you do this:

```
  example[:a][:c] = "test2"
```

What you are really doing is:

```
  hash = example() #=>       {:a => {:c => "test"}, :b => {}}
  hash[:a][:c] = "test2" #=>       {:a => {:c => "test2"}, :b => {}}
```

And, therefore, the hash is updated.